# How to add conditional CSS in ASP:menu control?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a menu control that gets the menu items from SiteNodeMap. So for one of the items, I need to set the border colour, width etc. How can I put if condition or eval in ASP code?

Here's my menu code:

```
<asp:menu ID="menu121" runat="server"  DataSourceID="mapDataSource" OnMenuItemDataBound="itemdatabound" >
//put eval condition here because I need this only for one item
           <StaticMenuItemStyle   borderstyle="Solid" borderwidth="1" bordercolor="Red" />
        </asp:menu>
```

If the field name is "Tasks", is should display a red border around Tasks.
Let me know if you need anything else.
~SRJ

Comment: What are the conditions for set the border color? - please, [edit] your question.

Comment: Sorry about that!

Comment: Check the generated html and write css classes to match it.

Comment: add the css to the SiteNodeMap control in your code.  there are various ways to add in the desired styles you need.